# ¿Cómo podría utilizar menos sentencias if/elif en este programa para hacerlo más eficiente?

Tags: python

!Buenos días!
Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python y hice este programa sencillo para validar una fecha de nacimiento, el cual funciona correctamente, pero abuse mucho de los condicionales if-elif y me gustaría saber cómo podría hacer el código más corto, elegante y eficiente.

La consigna del ejercicio es la siguiente:
Desarrollar un ejercicio en Python, donde:

1. Ingresar día de nacimiento (controlar dos dígitos de 1_31).
2. Ingresar el mes (controlar dos dígitos 1_12).
3. Ingresar el año (controlar mayor a 1920 - 2020).
4. Mostrar la fecha numérica y fecha larga:
   Ejemplo:
   Fecha 14/5/1980
   Fecha larga: 14 de mayo de 1980

El código del programa que hice es el siguiente:

```py
print('Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento en formato DD/MM/YYYY: ')
entrada = input().split("/")
day = int(entrada[0])
month = int(entrada[1])
year = int(entrada[2])

# Validar años.
if 1920 <= year <= 2020:
    # Validar meses.
    if 1 <= month <= 12:
        # Validar días.
        if 1 <= day <= 31 and month == 1:
            print(f'\n Fecha larga: {day} de enero de {year}')
        # Validar si el año es bisiesto.
        elif 1 <= day <= 29 and month == 2 and (year%400 == 0 or (year%4 == 0 and year%100 != 0)):
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de febrero de {year}')
        elif 1 <= day <= 28 and month == 2:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de febrero de {year}')
        elif 1 <= day <= 31 and month == 3:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de marzo de {year}')
        elif 1 <= day <= 30 and month == 4:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de abril de {year}')
        elif 1 <= day <= 31 and month == 5:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de mayo de {year}')
        elif 1 <= day <= 30 and month == 6:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de junio de {year}')
        elif 1 <= day <= 31 and month == 7:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de julio de {year}')
        elif 1 <= day <= 30 and month == 8:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de agosto de {year}')
        elif 1 <= day <= 30 and month == 9:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de septiembre de {year}')
        elif 1 <= day <= 31 and month == 10:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de octubre de {year}')
        elif 1 <= day <= 30 and month == 11:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de noviembre de {year}')
        elif 1 <= day <= 31 and month == 12:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de diciembre de {year}')
        else:
            print('El día no es válido.')
    else:
        print('El mes no es válido.')
else:
    print('El año no es válido.')

print(f'Fecha corta: {day}/{month}/{year}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes trabajar con un diccionario con los meses personalizados y acceder por el número del mes al nombre:

```
meses_nombres = {1: "enero", 2: "febero", 3: "marzo", 4: "abril", 5: "mayo", 
                 6: "junio", 7: "julio", 8: "agosto", 9: "septiemnre", 10: "octubre", 
                 11: "noviembre", 12: "diciembre"}
print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de {meses_nombres[month]} de {year}')
```

Answer (score 4):

Además de tener un diccionario con los nombres de los meses que te puede servir para construir el "formato largo", también puedes tener un diccionario con los días que tiene cada mes, que te puede servir para validar el día sin necesidad de la larga secuencia de `if`s.

Para el tratamiento de los bisiestos bastaría añadir a febrero un día más si el año es bisiesto. Para simplificar el código escribiré una función que retorne un booleano indicando si un año dado es bisiesto o no:

```py
def es_bisiesto(year):
  return year%400 == 0 or (year%4 == 0 and year%100 != 0)
```

(no he hecho más que extraer a una función una parte de tu código).

Ahora definimos los dos diccionarios que nos ayudarán en la tarea:

```py
dias_mes = {1: 31, 2: 28, 3:31, 4:30, 5:31, 6:30, 7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31}
nombre_mes = {1: "enero", 2: "febrero", 3: "marzo", 4: "abril", 5: "mayo", 6: "junio",
              7: "julio", 8: "agosto", 9: "septiembre", 10: "octubre", 
              11: "noviembre", 12: "diciembre"}
```

Y entonces el código de validación (a la vez que la impresión de la fecha larga) se reduce a lo siguiente:

```py
dias_mes[2] += es_bisiesto(year)
if 1920 <= year <= 2020:
    # Validar meses.
    if 1 <= month <= 12:
        # Validar días.
        if 1 <= day <= dias_mes[month]:
            print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de {nombre_mes[month]} de {year}')
        else:
            print('El día no es válido.')
    else:
        print('El mes no es válido.')
else:
    print('El año no es válido.')
```

### Alternativa

Podemos también encapsular en una función la parte en la que se valida si la fecha es buena o no. Podemos hacer que la función que lo comprueba retorne una pareja de valores: un booleano (que será `True` si la fecha pasa el test, o `False` si no lo pasa) y una cadena de error (que informará de por qué no pasó el test, o bien estará vacía).

A la hora de programar esa función podemos reducir su complejidad (los niveles de indentación) si miramos primero las condiciones de **no** pasar el test, para retornar inmediatamente si no lo pasa, y dejando para el final el caso de que pase todas para retornar `True`. Esta estrategia evita la anidación de ifs.

Por otro lado, usaré el truco adicional de mirar `if x in range()` para saber si una variable está en un rango dado (cuidado porque el extremo derecho del rango debe ser 1 más).

Con estas consideraciones una función de verificación podría ser así:

```py
def validar_fecha(year, month, day):
  dias_mes = {1: 31, 2: 28, 3:31, 4:30, 5:31, 6:30, 7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31}
  dias_mes[2] += es_bisiesto(year)
  if not year in range(1920, 2021):
    return False, "El año no es válido"
  if not month in range(1, 13):
    return False, "El mes no es válido"
  if not day in range(1, dias_mes[month]+1):
    return False, "El día no es válido"
  return True, ""
```

Y desde el programa principal la usaríamos así:

```py
print('Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento en formato DD/MM/YYYY: ')
entrada = input().split("/")
day = int(entrada[0])
month = int(entrada[1])
year = int(entrada[2])

ok, err = validar_fecha(year, month, day)
if ok:
  print(f'\nFecha larga: {day} de {nombre_mes[month]} de {year}')
  print(f'Fecha corta: {day}/{month}/{year}')
else:
    print(err)
```

Comment: Gracias, no se me había ocurrido hacerlo de esa forma.

Comment: No sabía que las condiciones booleanas podían retornar 1 o 0 además de True o False.

Comment: En realidad el booleano retornado es `True` o `False`, solo que si lo usas en una expresión aritmética, Python lo convierte en 1 o 0 respectivamente.

Comment: Tengo un problemita pequeño con el programa, que al principio cuando imprime 'Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento en formato DD/MM/YYYY: ' realiza un salto de línea. ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: Pon ese mensaje como parámetro de `input()` en vez de en un `print()` previo. O bien incluye en ese `print()` el parámetro `end=""` para que no añada el salto de línea

Comment: Gracias, ya lo pude solucionar.